# Responsive Android Design

Tags: android

How can I make a `responsive` `Android layout` without creating a lot of `XML` files with a lot of `values` in it ?

[image: Example]

My goal is to resize entire application based on the device size on which it is running. not by using xml files, but programmatically.

Comment: Please clarify your question and add addtional information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As android has lots of variety in device size and resolution , you shouldn't do whole design programmatically. you should follow design guideline . It will make your work easier though need multiple layout files. If your app is very small then try to use relative layout more to avoid design distortion . But I would like to suggest about multiple device support using design guideline. you can follow this [google developer link](http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html) it will minimize your work rather than using more xml files .